# Get the current path in a react component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-redux

To determine the styling of specific menu item, I am trying to get the current path in my Navigation component.

I tried some of the usual suspects already, but cannot get any results. Especially properties that I thought would be injected via React are not there.

`this.props.location` returns `undefined`

`this.props.context` returns `undefined`

I use `react 15`, `redux 3.5`, `react-router 2`, `react-router-redux 4`

```js
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import styles from './Navigation.css';
import NavigationItem from './NavigationItem';

class Navigation extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  getNavigationClasses() {
    let {navigationOpen, showNavigation} = this.props.layout;
    let navigationClasses = navigationOpen ? styles.navigation + ' ' + styles.open : styles.navigation;
    if (showNavigation) {
      navigationClasses = navigationClasses + ' ' + styles.collapsed;
    }
    return navigationClasses;
  }

  render() {
  /*
  TODO:  get pathname for active marker
  */

    let navigationClasses = this.getNavigationClasses();
    return (
      <div
        className={navigationClasses}
        onClick={this.props.onToggleNavigation}
      >

        {/* Timeline */}
        <NavigationItem
          linkTo='/timeline'
          className={styles.navigationItem + ' ' + styles.timeline}
          displayText='Timeline'
          iconType='timeline'
        />

        {/* Contacts */}
        <NavigationItem
          linkTo='/contacts'
          className={styles.navigationItem + ' ' + styles.contact + ' ' + styles.active}
          displayText='Contacts'
          iconType='contacts'
        />

      </div>
    );
  }
}

Navigation.propTypes = {
  layout: PropTypes.object,
  className: PropTypes.string,
  onToggleNavigation: PropTypes.func
};

export default Navigation;
```

Comment: @QoP It seems like this would only pass the context to a direct child, am I corrent?

Comment: to any component in the subtree, http://jsfiddle.net/3yLn5qzc/11/

Comment: @AnnaMelzer can you please share you router code please

Comment: This question is a year old. I do not have access to that project anymore.

Answer (score 28):

Add your component to router first

```
<Router path="/" component={Navigation}  />
```

You can get your path in

```
this.props.location.pathname
```

This is a readme for location

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/location.md

Comment: As I said: `this.props.location` returns undefined, therefore `this.props.location.pathname` throws an arror.

Comment: You must add your component to Router